# Sending data from frontend javascript to node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made the mistake of completing a massive website, then realizing I needed a server beyond the client side Firebase I utilized. However, I already have all of the functions created in JavaScript.

What I am trying to do, but no matter how long I look I cannot find how to do, is to send data from frontend JavaScript to backend Node.

Ideally what I hope is possible, is to take the function in client side, and instead of returning valueToSendToBackEnd, I send it to some place in node that knows when this function runs(it would be called with an onclick in client) and then utilizes the data for something else.

```
function getHtmlDataFromClientJavascript {
    var input1 = document.getElementById('htmlInputId').value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById('htmlInputId2').value;
    const valueToSendToBackEnd = { I1: input1, I2: input2 }
    //SomeMagicalFunctionThatSendsTheThingBelow
    valueToSendToBackEnd.sendToBackEnd();
}
```

I know I can get the data direct from HTML to node, but that would be a task that would take dozens more hours to recode due to the size of the website. If what I hope to do isn't possible, is there another option I have, or just HTML to node with a Post request in the HTML?

Comment: in order to send the value to the backend you need to have a backend server and database like MySQL or MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably look to the [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) package to do post request and then receive this post request in your backend with express router as this

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.post('/', function requestHandler(req, res) {
  res.end('Hello, World!');
});

const server = await app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that is going to work. So, to clarify,
In client I do:

$.post( '/isThisTagInHereCorrect', modelSave );

And in server

app.post('/isThisTagInHereCorrect', function requestHandler(req, res) {

so that the tag after the / are the same, and that is how the server determines which post it gets?

Comment: Nevermind, it is. One last question though, I still dont understand how to use the data I just sent to node.

I mean, how do I console.log in node what I sent?

Comment: u need to do console.log(req.body) you should take a look to this page https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req